# linq grouping ID base and insert common data into new Array

Tags: c#, linq

am working on collection set where the collection is groupby ID and i get some repeated data which is not so prefect so looking for some best handling so that i could get the expected result sample data below 
present collection looks like so

```
       [{
        "id": 116,
        "amgId": 168755,
        "amgName": "FIT",

        "prodQty": 4801,
        "prodMonth": "2020/03",
    },
    {
        "id": 117,
        "amgId": 168755,
        "amgName": "FIT",

        "prodQty": 3746,
        "prodMonth": "2020/04",
    }],
    [
    {
        "id": 61,
        "amgId": 168383,
        "amgName": "CIVIC",

        "prodQty": 0,
        "prodMonth": "2020/03"
    },
    {
        "id": 62,
        "amgId": 168383,
        "amgName": "CIVIC",

        "prodQty": 0,
        "prodMonth": "2020/04"
    }],
    expecting to be grouped like below
   [
  "amgId": 168755,
 "amgName": "FIT",
   "prodQty"{
 "prodQty1": 4801,
 "prodQty2": 3746,
  }
],
  [
 "amgId": 168383,
 "amgName": "CIVIC",
 "prodQty"{
 "prodQty1": 0,
 "prodQty2": 0,
 }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: so do you have a maximum of 2 of each?

Comment: its maximum of five each.I tried grouping them and then loop inside to insert them into new array but dint find it proper thought would be some better way to it. Thanks

Comment: GroupBy and then loop over the result and always take the first result should do it

Comment: Can prodQty be an array of values instead of prodQty1, prodQty2, etc.?

Comment: Group and loop the data and it should get all the loop data as prodQty value is different am inserting them in a new array inside as expected result sample but then looking for some insight if that can be handled better with LInq

Comment: Your expected result sample does not have an array for the prodQty values.  You would need something like
"prodQty": [4801, 3746] or "prodQtys": [{"prodQty": 4801}, {"prodQty": 3746}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it done like so and anyother wayI make it more efficient

```
 var grp = productionvolume.GroupBy(x => x.AmgId).Select(y => y.ToList()).ToList();
 foreach (var production in grp)
        {


            Dictionary<string, object> prodQty = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            Dictionary<string, object> Forecast_type = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            Dictionary<string, object> Month = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            Dictionary<string, object> Qty = new Dictionary<string, object>();


            prodQty.Add("AmgName", production.Select(a => a.AmgName).FirstOrDefault());
            prodQty.Add("AmgId",production.Select(id => id.AmgId).FirstOrDefault());
            int count = 0;

            foreach (var prod in production)
            {
                Forecast_type.Add("ForecastType"+count, prod.ForecastType );
                Month.Add("ProdMonth"+count, prod.ProdMonth);
                Qty.Add("ProdQty"+count,prod.ProdQty);
                count ++;

            }
            prodQty.Add("Forecast_type",Forecast_type);
            prodQty.Add("ProdMonth",Month);
            prodQty.Add("ProdQty", Qty);
            //prodQty.Add(Qty);
            prodQty_result.Add(prodQty);

        }
```